# Filtering database query based on form input

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I can't get my script fully operational.

I have it calculating properly but now need a query for fuel type.

```
<?php

include 'mysql_connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM fuel_price WHERE FuelType='Oil'" ;

$result = mysql_query($query);
$price= mysql_fetch_array($result);


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 echo "The Price Today is  ";

 echo "£"; echo $_POST['qtylitres'] * $price ['Price'];



 } else {

echo "Please select value";

}

?>
```

I need to to check fueltype selected on form and calculate total accordingly.

eg $query = "SELECT * FROM fuel_price WHERE FuelType='{$_POST['fueltype'];}'" ;

Please help anyone under pressure.

Thanks

Comment: Yikes! `WHERE FuelType='{$_POST['fueltype'];}'" ;` Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Comment: you are just about there: $query = "SELECT * FROM fuel_price WHERE FuelType='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fueltype'])."'"; isn't this working for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mysql multiply database value with form selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232428/php-mysql-multiply-database-value-with-form-selection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include 'mysql_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['inputEmail'] == ''){
        echo 'Please enter an email address';
    } else{
        // show price
        $fuelPriceQuery = sprintf("SELECT `Price` FROM fuel_price WHERE FuelType = '%s' LIMIT 1",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fueltype']));

        $fuelPriceResult = mysql_query($fuelPriceQuery);
        $price           = mysql_fetch_array($fuelPriceResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo 'The Price Today is £'.($_POST['qtylitres'] * $price['Price']);

        // insert email
        $addEmailQuery  = sprintf("INSERT INTO `subscribe`(`Email`) VALUES('%s')",
                            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputEmail']));
        $addEmailResult = mysql_query($addEmailQuery);
        if($addEmailResult){
            echo 'You have successfully subscribed';
        } else{
            echo 'Sorry, we could not subscribe you at this time. Please try again.';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Please select value";
}
```

A couple of things to note:

1. *Always* make sure to escape the user input by using `mysql_real_escape_string`, if you are not using prepared statements such as PDO, MySQLi, etc...
2. I added the `LIMIT` clause to the query so `mysql_fetch_array` will work, because if it returns more than one row, then you would have to handle it in a loop.
3. It is not necessary to use multiple `echo`s, in fact it is better if you use as few as possible.

Comment: you forgot the `order by` without that you will probably select the first fuel price from 1928.

Comment: @Johan: Huh? How do you know the table schema? :)

Comment: happy days.  Thanks a million.

I know this is bit much to ask but how do I add email address to different table in same query??

eg $u = "INSERT INTO subscribe `Email`='$_POST[inputEmail]'";

Thanks

Comment: @nuubee, that's an SQL injection hole you're posting there, right after some people have gone into great detail about how and why **not** to do that, please stop doing that.

Comment: @Shef, limit 1 without an order by is pointless, it just selects a "random" row.

Comment: @Johan: Yes, I agree it's pointless, but the OP has not shared the table schema so we can tailor the query to OP's requirements.

Comment: -1 @Shef, you have added an XSS hole in that code, you need to escape the output of echo using `stripslashes` or alike function.

Comment: @nuubee, NP but it's hard to lurk in the [php] tag seeing all the XSS and SQL-injections flying over in such great numbers.

Comment: @Shef, it's not a math result, it's `$_POST['qtylitres']` anything can be in there, wait a minute.... I was too hasty.

Comment: @Johan: Show me a sample XSS which would bypass `echo ($_POST['qtylitres'] * $price['Price']);`. Don't talk nonsense.;)

Comment: @Shef let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2992/discussion-between-johan-and-shef)

Comment: Hello I am trying to calculate fuel price and add email address at the same time.  Can I insert and select in same query??

Comment: @nuubee: No, you can't do a `SELECT` and `INSERT` in the same query. Do you want to insert the email before the `echo 'The Price Today is...`? Where do you want the `INSERT` to occur?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding. After the echo price if possible.

User email addresses will be stored in a seperate table called subscribe under field Email??

Comment: getting error Undefined variable: result.  Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @nuubee: Changed the code. I had forgotten an old variable in there. Copy it again and test it.

Comment: Shef price now working but doesn't seem to be adding Email.  

Getting echo 'Sorry, we could not subscribe you at this time. Please try again.';

Any Ideas??

Comment: @nuubee: Are you passing the input `inputEmail` with the form submit, does the table `subscribe` exist?

Comment: yes and yes.  Here is input <input type="text" name="inputEmail" value="Please enter email" onfocus="this.value=''"  />

and subscribe database has two cols one is ID and other Email. Not sure whats wrong??

Thanks again

Comment: @nuubee: Sorry, dumb me, didn't take a look at your query's syntax. I used it as it was. It must work with the updated code now.

Comment: Shef you are a life saver. How do I stop people from submitting form if email field empty? Its adding empty fields now at the moment.

Comment: Thanks.  Its not adding empty records in subscribe database anymore bit it still lets user see price even email input empty??

Sorry to hassle you. Thanks

Comment: @nuubee: Okay, that must be the final touch.

Comment: @nuubee: Accept the answer by clicking the empty tick below the vote count on the top left side of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fueltype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fueltype']);
$query = "SELECT price 
          FROM fuel_price 
          WHERE FuelType= '$fueltype'
          ORDER BY pricedate DESC
          LIMIT 1 ";
```

**Explanation**

1. Always use either PDO or `mysql_real_escape_string()`
2. Don't do `SELECT *`, only select the fields you need.
3. Put the injected `$var` in single quotes, or mysql_real_escape_string() will not work!
4. If you only need one price, select only 1. Use `limit 1` to get only 1 and `order by ... DESC` to get the latest.